# java threads and multithreading:How to synchronize threads

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-synchronization

I was doing my college assignment for java which includes a program for find sum and product of n numbers using two threads.I have written the following code however the threads are overlapping one another ie-code of both threads are being executed simultaneously.Someone please help me to rewrite the code so that the after only one thread finishes execution,the other one may start.Thanks in advance

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    class ThreadSum extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            int n, sum = 0, num;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter no of values");
            n = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter numbers");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                num = sc.nextInt();
                sum = sum + num;
            }
            System.out.println("The sum is:" + sum);
        }
    }

    class ThreadPro extends Thread {

        public void run() {
            int n, pro = 1, num;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter no of values");
            n = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter numbers");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                num = sc.nextInt();
                pro = pro * num;
            }
            System.out.println("The product is:" + pro);
        }
    }

    class pro {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            ThreadSum ts = new ThreadSum();
            ts.start();
            ThreadPro tp = new ThreadPro();
            tp.start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just add ```ts.join();``` after ```ts.start();```

Comment: what is the point in using multiple threads if you start the second one after the first is finished?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65677134/14346734.

Remember: threads are asynchronous. If you need them to be synchronous, don't use threads.

Please edit and let us know your point.