# How to "synchronize" threads to run one after another in order?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to make my method to print out 4 lines of "Hello world!", but my code seems to not work as I want. Is there a way that I have a guarantee that it will run as I want? Sometimes I get 2 lines, sometimes the words are in wrong order, and so on. Sometimes it prints words how I want, but mostly not.
Sorry for any mistakes in my code that can hurt your eyes, I'm still learning and im here because of it. Thanks for any advice.

```
public class PrintHelloWorld {

final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
private volatile String state = "inactive";

public void printHelloWorld() {
    LocksManager manager = new LocksManager();

    Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
        synchronized (manager.getObject(0)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                System.out.print("Hello ");
                try {
                    manager.notify(1);
                    state = "running t2";
                    while(!state.equals("running t1"))
                        manager.wait(0);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
        synchronized (manager.getObject(1)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                System.out.print("world");
                try {
                    manager.notify(2);
                    state = "running t3";
                    while (!state.equals("running t2"))
                        manager.wait(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    Thread t3 = new Thread(() -> {
        synchronized (manager.getObject(2)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                System.out.println("!");
                try {
                    manager.notify(0);
                    state = "running t1";
                    while (!state.equals("running t3"))
                        manager.wait(2);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    {
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            t3.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private class LocksManager {
    private volatile Object[] locks;

    public LocksManager() {
        locks = new Object[3];

        for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
            locks[i] = new Object();
    }

    public Object getObject(int number) {
        return locks[number];
    }

    public void wait(int number) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (locks[number]) {
            locks[number].wait();
        }
    }

    public void notify(int number) {
        synchronized (locks[number]) {
            locks[number].notify();
        }
    }

}
}
```

The output shoud look like this:

```
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
```

But sometimes it looks like this:

```
Hello world!
Hello !
worldHello !
worldHello !
world
```

Or this:

```
Hello !
world
```

Comment: Each of your threads has its own lock, so they can run in parallel. The handling of your notifications is quite hard to follow - it's likely you have just overlooked a possible path.

Comment: If you want sequential execution why are you using threads?

Answer (score 0):

Threads are supposed to be **Asynchronous**, which is the behavior you see in your executions.

If you need to force them to be synchronous, please take a look at Future's in https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial. You can make a List and iterate the list using an executor and the **.get** method to wait for a result of each thread.

I'm not sure about you use case, but threads is a very challenging subject.